# Zip pdf files from url

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to zip multiple pdf files from existing links using [archiver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver) npm module. I am able to zip multiple files from memory or local to my machine, but it doesn't work when I pass in urls in `fs.createReadStream()`.

[fs.createReadStream()](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/advanced/streams/how-to-use-fs-create-read-stream) tells me that all I need to do is pass in the path of the file that I want to stream the data from. I know I am doing something awfully wrong, can't get my head around what exactly it is.

```
var archiver =  require('archiver');
var archive = archiver('zip');

res.set('Content-Type', 'application/zip');
res.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=123.zip');

archive.pipe(res);

archive
   .append(fs.createReadStream('https://URL-1-XXX.pdf'), { name: 'file1.pdf' });
   .append(fs.createReadStream('https://URL-1-XXX.pdf'), { name: 'file2.pdf' });

archive.finalize(function(err, bytes) {
 if (err)
   throw err;

 console.log('done: ', bytes);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fs.createReadStream is used to read files stored on disk, not make HTTPS requests. I'd advise you to read the API docs a little further and look into the https module.

Try this instead:

```
var request = require('request');
archive
   .append(request.get('https://URL-1-XXX.pdf'), { name: 'file1.pdf' });
   .append(request.get('https://URL-1-XXX.pdf'), { name: 'file2.pdf' });
```